# What kind of uses could the Wavelength node be used for?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

One of the new features in 2.68 is the [*Wavelength node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/converter/wavelength.html#wavelength-node),
but I have yet to think of a good way to put this to use.. (though dispersion and diffraction immediately spring to mind)

What are some good use cases of this node? (And how is it different from a *Color Ramp node*?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One might use it to get some form of [iridescent effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence) (Wikipedia article). Elaborating on the idea that the perceived colour of parts of objects depends on the direction of the surface normal of each point on a surface with respect to our eyes. Compressing and rarefying a ribbed pattern around the scale of visible light wavelengths can change the colour we see as a result.

[image]